# Validating dates using moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I've got a little issues getting my dates validated using moment.js. Moment.js has the `isValid()` function. However, this does not seem to work in the manner I would expect it to work.

#### Code

```
var startDate = moment($('.input-start').val()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var endDate = moment($('.input-end').val()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

if (startDate.isValid() && endDate.isValid()) {
    // The script will never come here
    // Additionally it throws a TypeError saying isValid is unavailable for startDate
}
```

I think this illustrates my issue but if further details are required, please dont hesitate to ask.

Comment: when you do `moment().format(...)` it returns string in provided format. So all moment functions are lost. Remove `.format()`

Comment: @Rajesh Okay, thanks. But how can I check if a certain format is used?

Comment: I'm quite sure moment can be use as moment('your date','format').isValid()

Comment: @ssbb it gives valid for `moment("10-2-2016", "YYYY/MM/DD")`. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/vq3af7o7/)

Comment: you can force the check by adding true as parameter.
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: @ssbb Yup. Just posted an answer based on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by [@ssbb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3013690/ssbb), you will have to do

```
moment(dateString, format).isValid()
```

But here is the catch, `moment` has 4 parameters in constructor,

```
moment(dateString, format, timeZone, strict)
```

**Note:** Default value of `strict` is `false`

#### Sample

```js
var dateStr = "10/2/2016";

var format = "YYYY-MM-DD";
var date = moment(dateStr, format);
console.log(date.isValid(), date.format(format))

var date1 = moment(dateStr, format, undefined, true)
console.log(date1.isValid(), date1.format(format))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Format` function returns a string so you cannot apply the `isValid` function on it anymore.

If you want to check if two dates are valid, as per a specific format, you can do the following:

```
var startDate = moment($('.input-start').val(), 'YYYY-MM-DD').isValid();
var endDate = moment($('.input-end').val(), 'YYYY-MM-DD').isValid();

if (startDate && endDate) {
    ...
}
```

For more information check out the [official docs from MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) that have more information on the matter.